# Preserving text-chunk when inserting PNG

Tags: png, metadata

PNG image format has the useful capability of allowing generic text-chunks in the image. Like other classical metadata (exif) it would be great that they could be preserved after being inserted in a PDF generated by PDFLaTeX.

Is that possible?

Comment: if you use luatex perhaps but pdftex doesn't give access to the internal data and tex and doesn't load the image file at all, if you have a commandline image tool to extract the text it should be easy to arrange that tex inputs the text from an associated .txt file, if it exists

Comment: David, can you explain how to do with Luatex?

Comment: @rpapa no:-) but it may be possible as it has an `img` Lua library to extract metadata from images, so starting from the luatex manual and a spec (or example) of how text is encoded in PNG, something _may_ be possible (more possible than in pdftex which has no access to any internal image data)